# Blender keeps crashing to the point my laptop restarts itself from overheating when I render my image

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu

I’m currently working on a room design. Nothing too complicated bc is a beginner. I tried everything including lowering the cycles render number to as low as 10, switching to CUDA, etc. it even crashes when I render with Eevee. When I press render, no tiles show up and it just crashes.

It was fine the other night when I render the same file but with an angle that is closer to the objects of the room. But when I try to render it in a zoomed-out angle today, where the shape of the room is within the camera frame, it just won’t stop crashing.

FYI. The laptop I’m using is completely new, got it three days ago and it’s a Asus 2020 gaming laptop. 9th gen i7 intel core and nvidia 2060 processor

What do I do? I worked really hard on this project and I really don’t want it to go to waste just because I can’t render it and same an image :(

Comment: There's not much to go on in your description.  Your hardware sounds fine, assuming all your drivers are current.  Can you share your .blend?  It'll help diagnose your issue.

Comment: If the computer is brand new, it's possible that whatever graphics drivers it uses have received newer updates while it was "sitting on the shelf", First thing I would try is updating your graphics drivers to the latest version and see if that helps..